# Is there a research field which holds close connections between computational neuroscience and classical robotics

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience

Is there a research field which holds close connections between computational neuroscience and classical robotics, particularly building corresponding robots to  implement and test the theories from computational neuroscience ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's often called [Neurorobotics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurorobotics). There are several labs doing this kind of research. Here's a small sample:

- [Jeff Krichmar at UC Irvine](http://www.socsci.uci.edu/~jkrichma/).
- [The Neurorobotics Research Laboratory at Humboldt Unveristy](http://www.neurorobotik.de/index_en.php)
- [The Neurorobotics Lab at Drexel University](http://biomed.drexel.edu/new04/neurorobotics/)
- [Jun Tani at the Korea Advanced Institute of Science and Technology](http://neurorobot.kaist.ac.kr/)
- [NxR at Northwestern](http://nxr.northwestern.edu/)