# Prerequisite Request: Neurorobotics

Tags: neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, computational-modeling

For the newly emerging field, Neurorobotics. Can one list several highly recommended prerequisite courses prior to entering this field ? Except for classical machine learning, computational neuroscience.

Or specifically for either neuronally modelling and implementation of neural principles to robotic platforms etc...., does one need to establish a deeply solid foundation in something like analog/electric circuits analysis, Signal processing, Optics, Sensor fusions, kinematics etc.... by reading textbooks on them ?

Comment: I've never heard of neurobot. Have you looked at the cited citations on google scholar? http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=neurobot

Comment: If you are looking for journal publications related to neurorobotics in general, this is a very broad request and you should probably narrow it down.

Comment: You may also want to look at the labs mentioned in the answer to your [other question about neurorobotics](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/7672/is-there-a-research-field-which-holds-close-connections-between-computational-ne). Most labs list publications on their websites, which would be a good starting point.

Comment: This is a shopping question I'm voting to close it needs to be rephrased than can be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

The following book may help you:

Wermter, S., Palm, G., & Elshaw, M. (Eds.). (2005). Biomimetic neural learning for intelligent robots: Intelligent systems, cognitive robotics, and neuroscience (Vol. 3575). Springer. [LINK](http://www.homeshop18.com/biomimetic-neural-learning-intelligent-robots-intelligent-systems-cognitive-robotics-neuroscience/author:na/isbn:9783540274407/books/computers/product:23600193/cid:11167/)

It is about neurology and robotics. One should have a strong background in many subjects.
Search Google with the following phrase

> neurorobot filetype:pdf

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurobiotics